# Extract maximum (or last) values from a column based on the date in another column in Excel

Tags: excel, extract, powerquery

I have a huge excel file that I'm trying to sort by extracting the last value (column D) collected at the end of each day (column B). These data are coming from a rain gauge. Values in column D always increases during the day (but can also stay at 0) and goes back to 0 after midnight.
Data look like this:

| nb | date | mm | avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4669 | 23:39 23/9/2020 | 0.0 | 2.3 |
| 4670 | 23:44 23/9/2020 | 0.8 | 2.6 |
| 4671 | 23:49 23/9/2020 | 1.6 | 2.9 |
| 4672 | 23:54 23/9/2020 | 0.8 | 2.9 |
| 4673 | 23:59 23/9/2020 | 0.0 | 2.9 |
| 4674 | 0:04 24/9/2020 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 4675 | 0:09 24/9/2020 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 4769 | 23:39 24/9/2020 | 0.0 | 12.3 |
| 4770 | 23:44 24/9/2020 | 1.8 | 12.6 |
| 4771 | 23:49 24/9/2020 | 3.6 | 12.9 |
| 4772 | 23:54 24/9/2020 | 1.8 | 12.9 |
| 4773 | 23:59 24/9/2020 | 0.0 | 12.9 |
| 4774 | 0:04 25/9/2020 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 4775 | 0:09 25/9/2020 | 0.0 | 0.0 |

How can I do to simplify my table with only 1 value per day (last or maximum)?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have markdown sample data?

Comment: You're right, it can be easier for you. I just edited it

Answer (score 2):

I would put this through PowerQuery.

1. Format as table
2. Data > From Table/Range
3. Change formatting on Column B from Date/Time to Date assuming this is recognised as a Date/Time (Home > Data type: Date)
4. Order Column A, highest to lowest (Home > Sort > Z to A)
5. Add an index column (Add Column > Index Column)
6. Remove duplicates on Column B Date (Home > Remove Rows > Remove Duplicates)
7. Delete the index column (Home > Remove Columns > Remove Column)

You now have one value, the latest update, for each date.

The reason for the index column is because if you don't do this, the data will not remove duplicates based on the order. This forces the cache to update and store the new order of highest to lowest in step 4.

e: data posted instead of picture so here is the actual PowerQuery of it;

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"nb", Int64.Type}, {"date", type date}, {"mm", type number}, {"avg", type number}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type",{{"nb", Order.Descending}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Index", 0, 1),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Added Index", {"date"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Removed Duplicates",{"Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

To use this;

1. Format as table
2. Data > From Table/Range
3. Home > Advanced Editor and paste in my code however,

```
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
```

this line will change depending on what table this data is. So effectively just keep your line of this, not mine.

If this does not work due to the date not being a date, try the below code as it splits by space as a delimiter and then assigns the column as a date format;

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"date", type text}}, "en-GB"), "date", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"date.1", "date.2"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"date.2", "date"}}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"date", type date}, {"nb", Int64.Type}, {"mm", type number}, {"avg", type number}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type",{{"nb", Order.Descending}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Index", 0, 1),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Added Index", {"date"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Removed Duplicates",{"Index", "date.1"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: Thanks MrRight, I didn't know about PowerQuery. Sorry, I'm not expert in Excel. Nice tool! But I got stuck with the date format. I'm trying the other solution from JvdV but doen't work probably because of the same issue. Working on it...

Comment: I've edited another solution in that splits by delimiter first and then changes the date format.

Comment: I thought it would be fine but it stopped at the last line (Removed Duplicated). I have this : DataFormat.Error: We couldn't parse the input provided as a Date value. Details: 0:09

Comment: Updated again Laurent - I had the date.1 and date.2 mixed but it should be fine now.

Comment: Sorry again, it says now (at Table.RemoveColumns(#"Removed Duplicates",{"Index", "date.1"})) :DataFormat.Error: We couldn't parse the input provided as a Date value. Details: 31/12/2020 (I'm trying on my big table and that correspond to the first value after it was sorted). Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I concur that PowerQuery could be a very nice go-to solution for you. But it's also possible with formulas, for example:

[image]

Formula in `F2`:

```
=FILTER(A2:D15,B2:B15=XLOOKUP(INT(B2:B15),INT(B2:B15),B2:B15,,0,-1))
```

Comment: Yes I like this idea. But I tried and it didn't remove the duplicates. Basically, I have the same table not filtered. Probably something to do with the date format. I see the format is different from mine. I tried to convert the column but no success yet.

Comment: @Laurent, as long as you have actual dates in column B it doesn't matter what the custom numberformatting is.

Comment: Actually, I used PowerQuery to convert this column into dates, which is doing well automatically, but only for a limited number of lines (~1000). I have ~50k lines! Your formula works nicely until the dates are not converted. Damn I thought I had it! Excel is not my favourite tool.

Comment: @Laurent, you can probably do this using text-to-columns and transform this whole column at once in-place and use the formula just fine.

Comment: I tried to transform but didn't work. I updated a solution I found. Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: I also think your Excel will auto-recognize these dates when we use double hyphen: `=FILTER(A2:D15,B2:B15=XLOOKUP(INT(--B2:B15),INT(--B2:B15),B2:B15,,0,-1))`. Can you test that too @Laurent. No need to split, sort etc. Too much manual labour involved =)

Comment: Didn't work, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a way, thanks to @JvdV AND @MrRightSA for their recommendations.
This is what I did:

- Split column B with space (hours is now in B and days in C)
- Sort the table according to column A (largest to smallest)
- Remove the duplicates (next to "Text to Transform") using column C (days).

I don't think I would have found without your help. And I learned new stuff! I'm not giving up with Excel :) Thanks again.